# LiveCode File Creation

Tags: livecode

I'm not sure I'm asking this in the right place, but I've been working with LiveCode and I'm curious how the actual .livecode or .rev files get created. They look like some sort of mixed binary and LiveCode format. I've glanced through the source code, but it's not clear to me how the files are constructed.

Note that I'm talking about the project containers, not the standalones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure that this is the right place to ask. It isn't really a programming question, even though it is related. I think that the stackfile format is binary, but parts appear in clear text because that's what they are. Everything that is unrecognisable can be two things. It can be a definition of a byte range, or it can be the description of the stack, card or control itself. This description can contain user data, including clear text, but also movie data, picture data, a unicode stream, etc. Encrypted stacks appear as binary data.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask this question directly to RunRev...

To find out what happens when the file is saved, you have to look at the C++ functions inside the Livecode engine when the savestack message is sent and handled.

No other way to tell, so you have to ask those familiar with the innards of the engine.